# How to add an existing form to an existing VB Project

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add an existing form to a VB project(Ctrl-D) when I locate and copy the 3 files into the project the designer.vb form name appears with a small "VB" logo attached and the form is blank but has the correct filename/form name.
The code behind the form is correct and intact.

Comment: To add an existing Form to a different, Project see the Project Menu -> Add Existing Item. Browse to the Form location and import the Form class. The designer and .resx files will follow. Everything is copied to the current Project's folder. Note that the namespace is not changed.

Comment: You don't copy all files associated with the form. You only select the base form name that ends with .vb and that is not the designer.vb file. Just the core file. For example if your form name is frmUserPref then from the Add Existing Item dialog you would select the file named frmUserPref.vb and that's it. Visual Studio will take of the rest.

Comment: You can't just copy the files into the project/solution folder, you'd have to edit the project file (.vbproj) to include them. But you're better off using @Jimi's suggestion (which should be an answer).

Answer (score 0):

The way around the problem I found that actually works is:

1. Add a new form of the exact same name to the project.
2. Close Visual Studio / the project
3. Copy the 3 files you want to add ( replacing the "new" form you added )
4. Reopen Visual Studio / the project and your form should be there